# Keep 10 most recent folders and delete the others

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this cmd file, where I create a backup of a database

```sh
@echo off
Title Get FileName With Date and Time
Call :GetFileNameWithDateTime MyCurrentDate
echo %MyCurrentDate%
cd backups
MkDir %MyCurrentDate%
cd ..
cd bin
mysqldump.exe -u -p --single-transaction --routines --triggers --host test.com --databases database1 > "../backups/%MyCurrentDate%/testBackup.sql"
pause & exit
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetFileNameWithDateTime <FileName>
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set "MyDate=%%x"
set "%1=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%-%MyDate:~8,2%-%MyDate:~10,2%"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So What I'm trying to do is creating a script, which only allows 10 folders to exist, and the 10 folders should always be the latest. So if a 11 backup folder is made, then delete the oldest folder (1), and keep the latest (10)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more concise in PowerShell. This is written for a .bat fie script. When you are confident that the correct directories will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` command.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    Get-ChildItem -Directory 'C:\backup\*' | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 10 | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a solution that works, where I skip the first 10, and if there is more than that, then we delete.

```sh
set "delMsg="
for /f "skip=10 delims=" %%a in (
  'dir "backups\*" /t:c /a:d /o:-d /b'
) do (
  if not defined delMsg (
    set delMsg=1
    echo More than 10 found - only the 10 most recent folders will be preserved.
  )
  rd /s /q "backups\%%a"
)
```

Comment: If you only want ten directories, and wish to follow the idea you've specifically mentioned in your title, then you'd need to skip the first nine files, and delete the rest, in order that you can create a tenth. Alternatively if you are skipping the first ten, this particular answer would not follow the idea in your title, as you would be adding a directory, then limiting to the ten newest. Therefore you need to adjust the title to suit your code, or the code to suit your title.

Comment: @Compo The reason why I do 10 is because I add the 11 folder and then delete all but the 10 recent folders.

Comment: No need to try to explain, I was clear on what the end goal was, I was simply telling you that the title specifically gave a methodology, "Delete oldest folder before adding a new". The answer above would have meant that you were limiting to ten, then adding new, which inevitably would have menat that the resulting parent directory would still have held more than ten child directories, and not therefore have fulfilled the question paramethers.